# Getting error while running web application with crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am getting error as below

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,

 Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' 
 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Apparently it can't find the assembly file.  What's your question about it though?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is self-explanatory.
first probe: Is the DLL already in GAC (with given name, version)?
i.e Are the Crystal Report assemblies deployed, specifically those that were targeted while in development?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports components must be installed on the web-server, as they have COM dependencies.